# Django disable editing (but allow adding) in TabularInline view

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to disable editing ALL objects within a particular TabularInline instance, while still allowing additions and while still allowing editing of the parent model.

I have this trivial setup:

```
class SuperviseeAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
  model = Supervisee

class SupervisorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  inlines = [SuperviseeAdmin]

admin.site.register(Supervisor, SupervisorAdmin)
```

I have tried adding a `has_change_permission` function to `SuperviseeAdmin` that returns `False` unconditionally, but it had no effect.

I have tried setting `actions = None` in `SuperviseeAdmin` but it had no effect.

What might I be overlooking that could get this to work?

Comment: has_change_permission added to the trunk (coming for 1.5)!

Comment: did you ever get to solve this ?

Comment: I did not, but I also didn't revisit with newer versions of Django. So @Ahmet Navrus's comment that this became available in 1.5 may be relevant.

Comment: anyone could solve this?

Answer (score 4):

User django admin build in function has_change_permission()  and return false to restrict object Edit view.

```
class SuperviseeAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
  model = Supervisee

  def has_change_permission(self, request):
      return False

class SupervisorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  inlines = [SuperviseeAdmin]

admin.site.register(Supervisor, SupervisorAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating a separate inline class (see the [`InlineModelAdmin` docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin)) that uses a custom `ModelForm` where you can customise the the `clean` method to throw an error when trying to update:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.forms import ModelForm

from myapp.models import Supervisee


class SuperviseeModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta(object):
        model = Supervisee
        # other options ...

    def clean(self):
        if self.instance.pk:
            # instance already exists
            raise ValidationError('Update not allowed')
        # instance doesn't exist yet, continue
        return super(SuperviseeModelForm, self).clean()


class SuperviseeInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Supervisee
    form = SuperviseeModelForm


class SuperviseeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [SuperviseeInline]
```

Answer (score 0):

See this solution: [Django admin: make field editable in add but not edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860612/django-admin-make-field-editable-in-add-but-not-edit)

Override get_readonly_fields method:

```
def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
    if obj: # obj is not None, so this is an edit
        return ['name1',..] # Return a list or tuple of readonly fields' names
    else: # This is an addition
        return []
```

Comment: This works for normal admin, but not for inlines.

Answer (score -1):

just make all your fields readonly_fields in your admin.TabularInline as :

```
class SuperviseeAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
  model = Supervisee

  readonly_fields = ('your_field', 'your_field2',)
```

Answer (score -4):

```
class SuperviseeAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
  model = Supervisee

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SuperviseeAdmin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.list_display_links = (None, )
```