# Django Admin- disable Editing and remove "Save" buttons for a specific model

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a Django Model which I wish to be only readonly. No adds and edits allowed.

I have marked all fields readonly and overridden has_add_permission in ModelAdmin as:

```
class SomeModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False
```

Is there a similar `has_edit_permission`? Which can be disabled to remove "Save" and "Save and continue" buttons? And replace by a simple "Close and Return" button.

[Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields) Only mentions only about read only fields not about overriding edit permissions.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068843/permission-to-view-but-not-to-change-django

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/49560378

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Override the `templates/admin/submit_line.html` template and make the buttons whatever you want. You can do this for only the specific model by putting it in `templates/admin/[app_label]/[model]/submit_line.html`.

To conditionally show the default submit line or your custom submit line, override `ModelAdmin.change_view`, and add a boolean to `extra_context`:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    def change_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context=None):
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            extra_context = extra_context or {}
            extra_context['readonly'] = True

        return super(MyModelAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id, extra_context=extra_context)
```

Comment: Is overriding `templates/admin/[app_label]/[model]/submit_line.html` still supposed to work with Django 1.4? According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#templates-which-may-be-overridden-per-app-or-model) only certain templates can be overriden on a per app/model basis.

Comment: Perhaps not. However, both the `add_view` and `change_view` views add the `app_label` to the context, so you could use that to test for a particular app. Varying on the model will require overriding those two views on your `ModelAdmin` and adding `module_name` to the context as well.

Comment: @ChrisPratt `extra_context['readonly'] = True` doesn't work with Django 1.4. Somehow the variable never makes it into `submit_line.html`

Comment: It still works. The only change Django made in 1.4 was the add the `form_url` argument to the method definition. As long as you pass `extra_context` as a kwarg, as I did, it won't affect anything. However, if you just pass it as an argument, i.e. `change_view(request, object_id, extra_context)`, it gets stuffed into the `form_url` arg instead of `extra_context` where it belongs.

Comment: It's too bad Django 1.4 no longer lets `submit_line.html` be overridden on a per app/model basis. (Wonder why they got rid of that?) Anyhow, in `submit_line.html`, whether the individual buttons are shown is determined by different context bools, e.g. `show_save`, `show_delete_link` etc. How can I set these to hide/show buttons without actually overriding the template? I've tried `extra_context` but that doesn't work -- it seems that's only for, well, *extra* context, not changing existing context variables. Any thoughts?

Comment: These variables are defined in the `submit_row` template tag at `django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_modify.py`. You can override it creating your own template tag with the same name.

Comment: You can only override certain templates on a per app basis. submit_line.html is NOT one of these.

Comment: I don't think it works for a specific model admin, its a feature that wasn't added yet? https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11974  It doesn't work for me in django 1.6.7

Comment: @Mark "You can only override certain templates on a per app basis. submit_line.html is NOT one of these." yeah that seems to be the case but doc link?

Comment: @Mark never mind - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#templates-which-may-be-overridden-per-app-or-model

Answer (score 31):

For Django 1.11:

```
def has_add_permission(self, request, obj=None):
    return False

def changeform_view(self, request, object_id=None, form_url='', extra_context=None):
    extra_context = extra_context or {}
    extra_context['show_save_and_continue'] = False
    extra_context['show_save'] = False
    return super(YourModelAdmin, self).changeform_view(request, object_id, extra_context=extra_context)
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked a treat in combination with @mat_gessel's answer (I created a template in which `read_only` hides the save buttons), but on it's own, I'm not able to hide the 'Save and add another' button in Django 1.9 without overriding the template...

Comment: @ptim: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54202294 explains how to set `show_save_and_add_another=False` in Django < 2.1. For Django>=2.1 it is easier, it think.

Answer (score 20):

The easiest method would be disabling respective permissions in ModelAdmin class. For example, I have a Cart model that I want an admin to only view (list and details) and all I did was to add the following functions to CartAdmin class to disable delete, change and add

```
class CartAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['listing']

    def has_add_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False
```

The three methods has_add_permission, has_change_permission and has_delete_permission are the ones that disable add button, add form, edit form and delete buttons in the admin

Here is a sample output when viewing a record details in the admin that has the above permissions disabled

[image]

As you can see the diagram above, you only have close button and the details are not displayed in a form

Comment: Works perfectly in django 2+. You'll also get a nice "view" link in the admin list display.

Comment: Does it work in Django 1.11? Getting 403 Forbidden.

Answer (score 16):

I had same problem. I fixed it in admin.py

```
from django.contrib.admin.templatetags.admin_modify import register, submit_row as original_submit_row

@register.inclusion_tag('admin/submit_line.html', takes_context=True)
def submit_row(context):
''' submit buttons context change '''
ctx = original_submit_row(context)
ctx.update({
    'show_save_and_add_another': context.get('show_save_and_add_another',
                                             ctx['show_save_and_add_another']),
    'show_save_and_continue': context.get('show_save_and_continue',
                                          ctx['show_save_and_continue']),
    'show_save': context.get('show_save',
                             ctx['show_save']),
    'show_delete_link': context.get('show_delete_link', ctx['show_delete_link'])
})
return ctx
```

In MyModelAdmin class, add following function

```
@classmethod
def has_add_permission(cls, request):
    ''' remove add and save and add another button '''
    return False

def change_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context=None):
    ''' customize add/edit form '''
    extra_context = extra_context or {}
    extra_context['show_save_and_continue'] = False
    extra_context['show_save'] = False
    return super(MyModelAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id, extra_context=extra_context)
```

Comment: Of several of the alternative solutions offered, this one worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

Updated answer using Django 1.8 (Python 3 syntax).

There are three things to do:
1) extend the admin change form template, adding an `if` to conditionally suppress the submit buttons
2) override `admin.ModelAdmin.change_view()` and set a context var for the template `if` to read
3) prohibit unwanted `POST` requests (from DOM hacking, curl/Postman)

---

MyProject/my_app/templates/admin/my_app/change_form.html

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% load admin_modify %}
{% block submit_buttons_top %}{% if my_editable %}{% submit_row %}{% endif %}{% endblock %}
{% block submit_buttons_bottom %}{% if my_editable %}{% submit_row %}{% endif %}{% endblock %}
```

---

MyProject/my_app/admin.py (MyModelAdmin)

```
def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
  obj = MyModel.objects.get(pk=object_id)
  editable = obj.get_status() == 'Active'

  if not editable and request.method == 'POST':
    return HttpResponseForbidden("Cannot change an inactive MyModel")

  more_context = {
    # set a context var telling our customized template to suppress the Save button group
    'my_editable': editable,
  }
  more_context.update(extra_context or {})
  return super().change_view(request, object_id, form_url, more_context)
```

Comment: This is absolutely the best existing answer on this issue. Why so few upvotes? Also, if your template on custom path, use `template` property inside `MyModelAdmin` class.

Comment: By default Django will check a number of locations for the change_form_template `admin/myapp/model/change_form.html` and `admin/myapp/change_form.html`.

Comment: How do I disable it for all apps? (Following this, I can disable for individual apps)

Comment: @akashrajkn you could subclass `ModelAdmin` as `ReadOnlyModelAdmin` and use it for all the apps you define.  Maybe cleanest to define `template` on that subclass as `readonly_change_form.html`?

Comment: In addition, suggest defining `get_readonly_fields` so that fields are displayed as text, rather than form fields; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/7864099/2586761

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem - the easiest way to do this, is to include some custom JS.

In you admin.py file include

```
class Media:
    js = ('/static/js/admin.js',)
```

Then in your admin.js file, include the following JS.

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function($) {
         $(".submit-row").hide()
    });
})(django.jQuery);
```

The row is gone - it should work in all versions of Django too.

Comment: `has_delete_permission` removes delete action even list page. Overriding `change_view` does not work. Overriding `submit_row` template tag also changes buttons over all models.

Answer (score 4):

This has been possible for a while. The names are `has_add_permission`, `has_change_permission` and `has_delete_permission`. See the [django admin documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_add_permission) for reference. Here is also an example:

```
@admin.register(Object)
class Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False
```

Answer (score 2):

### Aug, 2022 Update:

You can remove **"SAVE" button**, **"Save and continue editing" button**, **"Save and add another" button** and **"Delete" button** from **a specific admin**.

For example, this is **"Person" model** in **"store" app** below:

```py
# "store/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Person"
        verbose_name_plural = "Person"
```

Then, this is **"Person" admin** in **"store" app** below:

```py
# "store/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

Then, this is how **"Add person" page** looks like:

[image]

Then, this is how **"Change person" page** looks like:

[image]

Then, this is how **"Select person to change" page** looks like:

[image]

Then, this is how **"Person" admin** on **"Store administration" page** looks like:

[image]

First, to remove **"SAVE" button**, set **"False"** to **"extra_context['show_save']"** in **"changeform_view()"** as shown below:

```py
# "store/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def changeform_view(self, request, object_id=None, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        extra_context = extra_context or {}

        extra_context['show_save'] = False # Here

        return super().changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
```

Then, **"SAVE" button** is removed from **"Add person" page** and **"Change person" page**. *Actually, **"SAVE" button** is replaced with **"Close" buttom** as shown below:

[image]

[image]

Next, to remove **"Save and continue editing" button**, set **"False"** to **"extra_context['show_save_and_continue']"** in **"changeform_view()"** as shown below:

```py
# "store/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def changeform_view(self, request, object_id=None, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        extra_context = extra_context or {}

        extra_context['show_save'] = False
        extra_context['show_save_and_continue'] = False # Here

        return super().changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
```

Then, **"Save and continue editing" button** is removed from **"Add person" page** and **"Change person" page** as shown below:

[image]

[image]

Next, to remove **"Save and add another" button**, return **"False"** in **"has_add_permission()"** as shown below. *After this, **"Add person" page** can no longer be accessed:

```py
# "store/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def changeform_view(self, request, object_id=None, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        extra_context = extra_context or {}

        extra_context['show_save'] = False
        extra_context['show_save_and_continue'] = False

        return super().changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)

    def has_add_permission(self, request, obj=None): # Here
        return False
```

Then, **"Save and add another" button** is removed from **"Change person" page** as shown below:

[image]

Then, **"ADD PERSON" button** is also removed from **"Select person to change" page** as shown below:

[image]

Then, **"➕ADD" button** is also removed from **"Person" admin** on **"Store administration" page** as shown below:

[image]

Next, to remove **"Delete" button**, set **"False"** to **"extra_context['show_delete']"** in **"changeform_view()"** as shown below:

```py
# "store/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def changeform_view(self, request, object_id=None, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        extra_context = extra_context or {}

        extra_context['show_save'] = False
        extra_context['show_save_and_continue'] = False
        extra_context['show_delete'] = False # Here

        return super().changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)

    def has_add_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False
```

Then, **"Delete" button** is removed from **"Change person" page** as shown below:

[image]

Actually, you can also remove **"Delete" button** by returning **"False"** in **"has_delete_permission()"** as shown below:

```py
# "store/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def changeform_view(self, request, object_id=None, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        extra_context = extra_context or {}

        extra_context['show_save'] = False
        extra_context['show_save_and_continue'] = False
        # extra_context['show_delete'] = False

        return super().changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)

    def has_add_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None): # Here
        return False
```

Then, **"Delete" button** is removed from **"Change person" page** as shown below:

[image]

Then, **"Action" select dropdown box** is also removed from **"Select person to change" page** as shown below:

[image]

In addition, you can make **the fields on "Change person" page** unchangeable by returning **"False"** in **"has_change_permission()"** as shown below:

```py
# "store/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def changeform_view(self, request, object_id=None, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        extra_context = extra_context or {}

        extra_context['show_save'] = False
        extra_context['show_save_and_continue'] = False
        # extra_context['show_delete'] = False

        return super().changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)

    def has_add_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None): 
        return False

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None): # Here
        return False
```

Then, **the fields on "Change person" page** are made unchangeable as shown below:

[image]

Then, **"✏️Change" button** is replaced with **"️View"** for **"Person" admin** on **"Store administration" page** as shown below:

[image]

In addition, you can remove **"Person" admin** from **"Store administration" page** by returning **"False"** in **"has_view_permission()"** as shown below:

```py
# "store/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def changeform_view(self, request, object_id=None, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        extra_context = extra_context or {}

        extra_context['show_save'] = False
        extra_context['show_save_and_continue'] = False
        # extra_context['show_delete'] = False

        return super().changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)

    def has_add_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None): 
        return False

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    def has_view_permission(self, request, obj=None): # Here
        return False
```

Then, **"Person" admin** is removed from **"Store administration" page** as shown below:

[image]

Finally, you can replace **"changeform_view()"** with **"render_change_form()"** which can also remove **"SAVE" button**, **"Save and continue editing" button** and **"Delete" button** with **"context.update()"** as shown below:

```py
# "store/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    
    # Here
    def render_change_form(self, request, context, add=False, change=False, form_url='', obj=None):
        context.update({
            'show_save': False, # Here
            'show_save_and_continue': False, # Here
            # 'show_delete': False, # Here
        })
        return super().render_change_form(request, context, add, change, form_url, obj)

    def has_add_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None): 
        return False

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    def has_view_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False
```

Comment: how to display show_save and show_close together?
When I activate both, only the save displays.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this package [Django Admin View Permission](https://github.com/ctxis/django-admin-view-permission). This package adds a `view permission` for the specified models and handles the other stuff automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the excellent [answer from @mat_gessel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36019597/2586761), here's my solution:

The main differences are UX'y:

- use [messages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/#module-django.contrib.messages) and [redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.redirect) (with [reversing-admin-urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls)), rather than `HttpResponseForbidden` to prevent a save
- define [get_readonly_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_readonly_fields) conditionally to prevent un-saveable inputs being displayed

Also:

- [override change_form.html](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) app-wide, because `read_only` is such a useful, non-invasive enhancement
- define [has_delete_permission](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_delete_permission) (may not be required by the OP)
- test `request.method != 'GET'` to prevent `PATCH` and friends (not altogether sure if this is required, tbh)

### my_app/admin.py

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.shortcuts import redirect

from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib import messages


class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # let's assume two fields...
    fields = (field1, field2)

    def changeform_view(self, request, object_id=None, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        if object_id:
            extra_context = extra_context or {}
            extra_context['read_only'] = True

            if request.method != 'GET':
                messages.error(request, "Cannot edit a MyModel object")
                return redirect(
                    reverse('admin:myapp_mymodel_change', args=[object_id])
                )

        return super(MyModelAdmin, self).changeform_view(request, object_id, extra_context=extra_context)

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj:
            # display all fields as text, rather than inputs
            return (field1, field2)
        else:
            return []
```

### admin/change_form.html

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% load admin_modify %}
{# remove the save buttons if read_only is truthy #}
{% block submit_buttons_top %}{% if not read_only %}{% submit_row %}{% endif %}{% endblock %}
{% block submit_buttons_bottom %}{% if not read_only %}{% submit_row %}{% endif %}{% endblock %}
```

(Tested on Django 1.9: heads up: some imports have moved since then, eg `reverse`)

Comment: how to display show_save and show_close together?
When I activate both, only the save displays.

Comment: @register.inclusion_tag('admin/submit_line.html', takes_context=True)
def submit_row(context):
  ctx = original_submit_row(context)
  ctx.update({
    "show_close": True,
    })
    return ctx

Answer (score 0):

To show close button

> app_name/admin.py

```
from django.contrib.admin.templatetags.admin_modify import register, submit_row as original_submit_row

...
class YourappAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
...
    @register.inclusion_tag('admin/submit_line.html', takes_context=True)
    def submit_row(context):
        ctx = original_submit_row(context)
        ctx.update({
            "show_close": True,
        })
        return ctx
...
```