# How to customize the submit_line.html or any non-editable template in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

"Templates which may be overridden per app or model
Not every template in contrib/admin/templates/admin may be overridden per app or per model. The following can:

app_index.html

change_form.html

change_list.html

delete_confirmation.html

object_history.html

For those templates that cannot be overridden in this way, you may still override them for your entire project. Just place the new version in your templates/admin directory. This is particularly useful to create custom 404 and 500 pages."

---

Where must I put the submit_line.html file in order to change it? I have got my TEMPLATE DIRS set up for multiple paths. This is what my file structure looks like:

```
app/
    templates/
        app/
project_name/
templates/
    admin/
        project_name/
            app/
```

Comment: Which Django Template you want change?

Comment: @FilipeManuel I would like to change submit_line.html *edit: on title of question

Comment: Have you tried this page? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates or this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8447818/939803

Comment: @FilipeManuel, I had been looking on the first link and cannot make it work. The second link, since its posting, has been updated and doesn't work.

Comment: Try putting in "templates/admin" as written on documentation. In your case in templates of your project app.

Comment: I have, as written in my question. Have I done it wrong?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34398/discussion-between-zac-and-filipe-manuel)

Comment: @FilipeManuel Your solution is working for me but how can I show the save and other optios only to superuser. Thanks for Your hint